# iOS system icons and custom buttons

Tags: ios, button, system

i'm working on my first app and the problem a have is that the application interface design is quite customised, (even though it is a tab bar based app). now in one of the view controllers i need to present the user with the print interaction controller to print images. the thing is i don't use a navigation bar or a toolbar system or otherwise. i have managed to attach a target action method to a custom button. however, apple states that the printing interface should be presented by a system button (the one that looks like an arrow, kind of). question is: is there any way of putting a system icon inside a button that is not inside a (bar)?, or would it be ok to somehow tell the user (with an overlay or something) that tapping the button i'm using (the button is a red ribbon coming down from a picture frame) they will get the printing options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to consider having a toolbar at the top of the view for this particular tab.  Just appearing on this tab. This would make the issue moot.

You could also, have the tool bar "slide in" and "slide out" from the top to provide access to this (and other?) actions.  A single or double tap could instigate such an action.

Unfortunately, Apple doesn't expose the images for the custom bar button items in any reasonable manner.  If you'd like access to them, I suggest using the bug reporter system at Apple's developer site to request that.

Comment: hi, thanks for taking the time to answer. the necessities of the view hierarchy, the app look and feel and my skill level make the solution i described the most suitable for me, for this particular problem. a sliding toolbar was one of the design decisions i considered at concept study level for implementing the feature but as i said at the beginning there are reasons for going with the custom button. thanks again for the answer though which was good.

Answer (score 1):

[Apple says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/Printing/Printing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010156-CH12-SW7):

> Although the print button can be any
>   custom button, it is recommended that
>   you use the system item-action button
>   shown in Figure 6-1.

I'd interpret that to mean that you can use your own button if you want to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer which is informative, since you are right of course and the HIG says just that.